# Simple PDF not rendering in Adobe PDF Reader

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, adobe

I am trying to understand the structure of a PDF file and using some examples I wrote a simple pdf file.

```
%PDF-1.4
1 0 obj<</Producer (TSR)>> endobj
2 0 obj<</Type/Catalog/Pages 3 0 R>>endobj 
3 0 obj<</Type/Pages/Kids [ 4 0 R ]/Count 1>>endobj 
4 0 obj<</Type/Page/MediaBox[0 0 200 400]/Contents 5 0 R /Resources <</ProcSet 6 0 R /Font << /F1 7 0 R>> >> >>endobj 
5 0 obj<</Length 42>> stream
BT /F1 24 Tf 50 100 Td(Hello World)Tj ET
 endstream endobj
6 0 obj [/PDF /Text] endobj 
7 0 obj<</Type/Font/Subtype/Type1/Name/F1 /BaseFont/Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding>>endobj 
xref
0 7 
0000000000 65535 f
0000000010 00000 n
0000000044 00000 n
0000000088 00000 n
0000000141 00000 n
0000000260 00000 n
0000000377 00000 n

trailer<</Size 7/Root 2 0 R /Info 1 0 R>>
startxref
474
%%EOF
```

This renders as expected in most PDF readers (Chrome, Firefox and Edge) but not in Adobe PDF Reader.

Adobe only renders a blank page and if you zoom out, an error is reported:

[image]

Any ideas on how to correct the error?

Comment: Your trailer dictionary has a /Size of 7, and your xref declares 7 objects starting from object number 0. That means the highest object number in the file must be 6 (0->6 = 7 objects). But your Page declares a Font Resource 'F1' with an object number of 7. You need to increase the /Size to 8, change xref to '0 8' and add another line to the xref table with the offset of object 7.

Comment: KenS is right. But you also need a `/Parent 3 0 R` in your `/Page` object.

Comment: and @johnwhitington thanks. I added both corrections and it seems the /Parent 3 0 R was the issue. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.